# Moving labels on chart

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to move the label for every other point in the series starting at 1, below the point, and every label for every other point starting at 2, above the point. Is there a way to 'skip' like using a regular "for..next" loop? It works for all of points if i execute the first part of the if, but I'm not sure how to make it do only every other point.

```
Sub MoveLabels()

  Dim objPt As Point

        For Each objPt In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points

                objPt.DataLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionBelow
                objPt.DataLabel.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter         
                objPt.DataLabel.VerticalAlignment = xlTop
                objPt.DataLabel.Orientation = xlHorizontal

        Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I had in mind:

```
Sub MoveLabels()

    Dim objPt As Point
    Dim LabelPosition as xlDataLabelPosition
    LabelPosition = xlLabelPositionBelow   ' Initialize

    For Each objPt In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points

            objPt.DataLabel.Position = LabelPosition 
            objPt.DataLabel.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter         
            objPt.DataLabel.VerticalAlignment = xlTop
            objPt.DataLabel.Orientation = xlHorizontal

            ' Toggle label position
            LabelPosition = Iif(LabelPosition = xlLabelPositionBelow, xlLabelPositionAbove, xlLabelPositionBelow)
    Next
End Sub
```

Or you could use a FOR I = 1 to .... Points.Count and set the position based on I MOD 2

Comment: I updated the code and was wondering if you could clarify what you mean? I tried applying your answer but it didn't work.